# finishWriting is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 6.0

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, avassetwriter

I use `AVAssetWriter` to encode video from image set:

```
[assetWriter finishWriting];
```

and this method generates warning in iOS 6.

```
[assetWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:<#^(void)handler#>];
```

This is the way how I should apply it in iOS 6. Could anyone help me with applying it

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to check whether it's finished. The completion handler is a block. It will be called by the system when the writing is finished. Try it.

```
[assetWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^(){
    NSLog (@"finished writing");
}];
```

Comment: [assetWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^(){
          
        }completionHandler:^ (BOOL finished){
            if (finished) {
                NSLog (@"finished writing");}
        }
         ];   can u explain like this,this code having errors

Comment: [assetWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^(){
    NSLog (@"finished writing");
}]; this one dosen't work i try it.It crash the app please help me

Comment: Instance method '-finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:' not found (return type defaults to 'id') warning

Comment: Could you paste your code here? I can't see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: i want to know how to stop assetWriter

Answer (score 1):

This is writer Start code

```
 NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs1];
    NSError *movieError = nil;
    [assetWriter release];
    assetWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:movieURL
                                            fileType: AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
                                               error: &movieError];
    NSDictionary *assetWriterInputSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                              AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:FRAME_WIDTH], AVVideoWidthKey,
                                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:FRAME_HEIGHT], AVVideoHeightKey,
                                              nil];
    assetWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo
                                                          outputSettings:assetWriterInputSettings];
    assetWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
    [assetWriter addInput:assetWriterInput];

    [assetWriterPixelBufferAdaptor release];
    assetWriterPixelBufferAdaptor = [[AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor  alloc]
                                     initWithAssetWriterInput:assetWriterInput
                                     sourcePixelBufferAttributes:nil];
    [assetWriter startWriting];

    firstFrameWallClockTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    [assetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime: CMTimeMake(0, TIME_SCALE)];

    // start writing samples to it
    [assetWriterTimer release];
    assetWriterTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f/60.0f
                                                        target:self
                                                      selector:@selector (writeSample:)
                                                      userInfo:nil
                                                       repeats:YES] ;
```

This is writer stop code

```
  if (isRecording) {
        isRecording = NO;
        [_session stopRunning];
        [assetWriterTimer invalidate];
        assetWriterTimer = nil;


        [assetWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^(){
            NSLog (@"finished writing");
        }];


        [self loadOvelay];

    }
```